# VLC Convert/Save Not Working In Linux Mint 21.2

Tags: installation, vlc, linux-mint, apt, cinnamon

Self-explanatory title.

I recently installed Mint Cinnamon 21.2 on a new PC, and when converting files from MP4 to MP3 with VLC, the output file is not saved.

What I get is an "MP3" file with 0 bytes filesize. The program appears to run in the VLC window, but this is all that comes of it. I am not getting any error messages either so I don't know what is going on.

Have tried updating and reinstalling VLC to no avail. Previously I have had no problem doing this on Mint.